# Android Studio build release with warning can't find referenced class

Tags: android, android-studio

When I build my application with signed APK I get a lot of "can't find referenced class" errors.  I did put some of these don't warn messages in my pro guard-rules.pro (for app) but then when I run the release Build Variant it fails on JSON not able to recognize fields.
The following are my don't warn statements I put earlier but removed:

```
#Warnings to be removed. Otherwise maven plugin stops, but not dangerous
#-dontwarn android.support.**
#-dontwarn com.sun.xml.internal.**
#-dontwarn com.sun.istack.internal.**
#-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
#-dontwarn org.springframework.**
#-dontwarn java.awt.**
#-dontwarn javax.security.**
#-dontwarn java.beans.**
#-dontwarn javax.xml.**
#-dontwarn java.util.**
#-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
#-dontwarn com.google.common.**
#-dontwarn com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.**
#
```

When I have removed those I get the following warns:

Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry

I am not sure if my dependencies such as:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0"
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.3'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'jackson:jackson-asl:0.9.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
```

are getting put in the release build.  Currently they are in app's build.gradle  file.  Should I put them somewhere else?

thanks
-Sonam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work.  I put back the "-dontwarn" statements.  I also had to put the following statements to not obfuscate my model getter/setters as it was not able to marshall to their object types.

```
-keep public class your.domain.package.* {
  public *** get*();
  public void set*(***);
}
```

This got my app working.

Comment: you need to put that in your app level proguard-rules.pro

Comment: do you want to paste your proguard-rules.pro?

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled proguard for signed apk, exclude the packages/classes/.. in the proguard rules file.

Comment: Can you show an example?  like -keep  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer?